# cant resplit after cicle. it says "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'join'")

Tags: python, join, split

cant split textNoZap after cicle (it says "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'join'"). Can somebody say what wrong i do:

```
text=str(input("tap you text here: "))
textNoZap=[0]
for leter in text:
    if leter != ",":
        textNoZap.append(leter)
    else:
        textNoZap.append(" ")
del textNoZap[0]
print(textNoZap)
textNoZap=textNoZap.join()
textNoZap=textNoZap.split()
print(textNoZap)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, in google can't find, all your answers help me, you are best)!
i do it earlier by replace, but want to understand what do wrong in join or split.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `textNoZap.join()`, but that is the wrong way of using that function. You should write it like that:

```
textNoZap = ''.join(textNoZap)
```

In those quotes before `.join()` you put anything you need to join your list with

Answer (score 0):

Both 'join' and 'split' are methods of the string object, not list object. That is why you get this error. Your question can be easily solved by a quick google search yourself.

Answer (score 0):

**I don't know your expected behaviour, I'm assuming you want to try to change all the commas in a string to spaces.**

Lists have no function `split()` or `join()`

The simple and easy method (builtin):

```
text=str(input("tap you text here: "))
text = text.replace(",", " ")    #Replaces ',' with ' '
print(text)
```

The method with lists that it seems you want:

```
text = str(input("tap you text here: "))
textNoZap = []
for leter in text:
    if leter != ",":
        textNoZap.append(leter)
    else:
        textNoZap.append(" ")

final_text = ''
for i in textNoZap:
    final_text += i
print(final_text)
```

Or (**From FSTMAX answer**):

```
text = str(input("tap you text here: "))
textNoZap = []
for leter in text:
    if leter != ",":
        textNoZap.append(leter)
    else:
        textNoZap.append(" ")
textNoZap = ''.join(textNoZap)
print(textNoZap)
```